# If J is a 101×101 matrix with all entries equal to 1 and let I denote the identity matrix of order 101. Then what is the determinant of J-I?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $J$ is a $101\times 101$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$ and let $I$ denote the identity matrix of order $101$. Then what is the determinant of $J-I$ ?

Comment: $100$ is the answer.

Comment: Please, explain me. I want to know the procedure.

Comment: What can you say about the diagonal of $J-I$?

Comment: All entries of the diagonal are zero.

Comment: Ok, work with $2 \times 2$, $3 \times 3$ matrices of this type, and see if you can spot a pattern for an $n \times n$ matrix.

Comment: Yes, I'll explain. The easy answer was just throw it into Matlab and compute, I'll give you a general formula now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $J$ be the $n\times n$ matrix with all entries equal to $1$ and let $I$ be the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Furthermore, let $A=-I$ and let $u=v=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\\vdots\\1\end{array}\right)$. Then $J-I=A+uv^T$, such that by [this Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma):
$$\det(J-I)=\det\left(A+uv^T\right)=\left(1+v^TA^{-1}u\right)\det(A)$$

- $A=-I$, such that $\det(A)=(-1)^n$.
- $A^{-1}=-I$, such that $A^{-1}u=\left(\begin{array}{c}-1\\\vdots\\-1\end{array}\right)$ and $v^TA^{-1}u=-n$, thus

$$\det(J-I)=(1-n)(-1)^n$$
and for $n=101$ you get 
$$\det(J-I)=(1-101)(-1)^{101}=100.$$

Answer (score 7):

The characteristic polynomial of $J$ is
$$
\det(J-XI)
$$
where $X$ is an indeterminate. However, $J$ has just two eigenvalues, namely $101$ and $0$, the latter with multiplicity $100$. Therefore the characteristic polynomial is
$$
(0-X)^{100}(101-X)
$$
and evaluating this polynomial at $X=1$ gives the answer.

More generally, if $J$ has order $n$, the characteristic polynomial is
$$
(0-X)^{n-1}(n-X)
$$

Note. The algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $n$ is at least $1$, whereas the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ is exactly $n-1$, so also the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $0$ must be $n-1$ (as it cannot be larger than $n-1$ because of the other eigenvalue).

Comment: Very nicely done and explained +1

Comment: @egreg can you please explain how you got characterstic polynomial as $(0-X)^{100} $ × (101-X) and why did you evaluated this polynomial at X= 1?

Comment: @YannicMuller Isn’t it explained in the final note? About evaluation at $1$, the characteristic polynomial at$1$is exactly the determinant of $J-I$.

Comment: @egreg why you are evaluating J-I is  clear but it's not clear why J must have all eigen values 0 except 1 101 . Can you please give a reason for that?

Comment: @Tim the matrix J has rank 1, so 0 is an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity 100. Its algebraic multiplicity cannot be more, because of the eigenvalue 101. There’s no space for orhers.

Answer (score 0):

Try for $3\times 3$ matrix and an identity matrix $I_3$ you get the determinant of $J-I$ as $2$ then what will the detreminant of $101\times 101$ matrix its $100$. Note diagonal elements become $0$. Hope its clear.

Comment: But, if you take 2×2 matrix, then the determinant of J-I is -1......…!

Comment: That the $3\times3$ case gives $2$ as an answer is ofcourse no proof that the $101\times101$ case will give $100$ as an answer.

Comment: Then should i use cayley hamilton theorem

Comment: This does not provide a mathematically sound answer.